# Загрузка в веб-приложение файла из Google Drive

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование, google-drive

Нужно загрузить в веб-приложение файл из Google Drive для обработки этого файла при помощи функций HTML5, не покидая страницы веб-приложения. Например, фото для редактирования через CANVAS или аудиофайл для редактирования через Web Audio API. Как это сделать?

Через JavaScript и Google Drive API я авторизуюсь, нахожу нужный файл и получаю ссылку на него. Но т. к. файл находится на другом домене я не могу его передать в нужные обрабатывающие функции HTML5 из-за ограничений CORS. Если бы это был файл на другом домене, не требующем авторизации, то я бы через AJAX передал ссылку на файл в PHP-скрипт, загрузил бы файл этот файл  PHP-скриптом и вернул его содержимое в веб-приложение, после чего смог бы с ним работать. Но, т. к. файл находится в Google Drive, то PHP-скрипт не может получить к нему доступ без авторизации.

Может быть можно передать в PHP-скрипт какой-нибудь token авторизации или что-то подобное?

Если использовать для авторизации и поиска файла PHP-скрипт, то как это сделать, не покидая страницы веб-приложения?

Или как по-другому решить поставленную задачу?